# Files have been deleted after deploy

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm using Azure DevOps to deploy my source in a WebApp.
I have two pipelines for two projects, the first project have been deployed like a charm, but the second not!

When I deploy the second project for a moment I saw the files in wwwroot folder from Kudo Editor, but after some seconds the files disappear and return the old files (webapps folder and hostingstart.html)

I noticed an AppSetting that not appear in first WebApp after deploy: 
WEBSITE_ENABLE_SYNC_UPDATE_SITE
But in documentation I didn't find something that impact it.

Ps: Perhaps wrong, I'm using the same AppService Plan in both WebApp. I think this not impact because the first project works well.

Some help?

Edit:

In /data/SitePackages/ has all zip's from my tries of release,
so the deploying is working, but for some reason instead of unzip in wwwroot folder, only appear after release a webapps folder inside wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

In you web app deploy task, under additional deployment options, make sure that you have the same deployment method for both of the deployments.

Ideally, Web Deploy.

[image: Additional Deployment Options]

Comment: both are auto detect
As I told, The file appear in server (looking with Kudo), but after few seconds all files disappear and original files come back

Comment: can you try setting both to web deploy and see how it goes?

Comment: I wrote with edit in my question. In /data/SitePackages/ has all zip's from my tries of release